# Sending mail with bash argument from command line in subject

Tags: linux, bash, mailx

I have the following code and I wanted the argument `-s` too to use the first argument of my bash script. How do I ensure it happens as it prints `$1` straight for the subject, though the message body has `$1` interpreted correctly as it goes through the `echo` statement.

```
echo "Converse Log Labels $1" | mailx -a conversation_logs_"$1".tsv -s "Converse Logs Labels Data "$1"" vk@aol.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "Converse Log Labels $1" | mailx -a "conversation_logs_$1.tsv" -s "Converse Logs Labels Data $1" vk@aol.com
```